# paramiko.exec_command() not executing and returns "Extra params found in CLI"

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, paramiko

I am trying to ssh a server using Paramiko and execute a command. But the paramiko.exec_command() returns with an error.Why is this happening?

This is my Python script:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.126.141.132', username='usrm', password='passwd')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show chassis")

print(stdout.readlines())

ssh.close()
```

When executed it returns with this message:

> ['Extra params found in CLI, this is not supported, exiting the CLI session:\n']

I am using Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit) with Paramiko on Windows.

I have tried the commands manually and it is working.

Comment: provide full trace

Comment: Check if `ssh usrm@ip show chassis` works from command line.

Comment: @whjm Tried the command in Putty. It is giving the chassis info as expected. Tried some other commands too which give valid outputs. But the script gives that message above. Don't know why.

Comment: @dmaneesh7 -- Not quite sure what you mean by *tried in putty* but you have to run the `ssh ... show chassis` command in a *shell* (like `bash`).

Comment: As I said you have to try it with the ***ssh*** command (usually available on any Unix/Linux systems).

Comment: @whjm As you suggested I installed a Cygwin Terminal and SSH'd the server with the command...it came up with the "Extra params" error..
Command I executed: ssh usrm@10.126.141.132 "show chassis"
Output: 'No entry for terminal type "dumb";
using dumb terminal settings.
Extra params found in CLI, this is not supported, exiting the CLI session:'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest comment:

> I installed a Cygwin Terminal and SSH'd the server with the command...it came up with the `Extra params` error. Command I executed: `ssh usrm@10.126.141.132 "show chassis"`, Output: `No entry for terminal type "dumb"; using dumb terminal settings. Extra params found in CLI, this is not supported, exiting the CLI session:`

it sounds like the `usrm` account's *login shell* on the SSH server is not allowed to run commands in the non-interactive way. To solve the problem you have to use `invoke_shell()` like this:

```
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.sendall('show chassis\r')
s = chan.recv(4096)
print s
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution it is working...recv() returns everything on the shell and also \r\n,the prompt # and b'...is there a way to prevent this or should I have to just format the output?

Comment: It's like you're manually interacting with the shell and `recv()` (and `recv_stderr`) will return everything including shell prompts.

Comment: found a way to remove those special charatcers...recv() returns `bytes`...by using `recv().decode("UTF-8")` we will get a proper unicode string without b' and the escape characters interpolated...