# Paramiko invoke_shell() returns command text and not results

Tags: python, paramiko

Problem:

error with ssh.exec_command : Extra params found in CLI, this is not supported, exiting the CLI session. It's a Cisco box with limited ssh functionality/dumb terminal support only.

Seems like the solution:

Link with my exact issue, but not working for me:
[paramiko.exec_command() not executing and returns "Extra params found in CLI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090445/paramiko-exec-command-not-executing-and-returns-extra-params-found-in-cli)

My code:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('my host', username='admin', password='pass')

#stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show version")

#print(stdout.readlines())

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.sendall('show version\r')
s = chan.recv(4096)
print s

ssh.close()
```

Output:

```
root@salt01-master tmp]# python ssh_cimc.py                                    
show version
```

Just the command itself, no sort of return value. If I point the script to a regular linux box and use uptime or ifconfig, I'm still getting the text output of the command and not results.

Comment: Sometimes you have to end the command with `\r\n` or even `\n`-only, depending on the remote server. The default "end of line" in SSH is `\r\n`

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: add a line `time.sleep(5)` after `sendall` and see if it helps.

Comment: time.sleep() works. Thanks for that. Curious but I'll take it. Getting ready for a datacenter move/re-ip and this will help immensely to reconfigure the army of servers. Cheers !

Comment: @pynexjbut why does it works? I've got a similar issue and your advice helped me too.